# Organizing Flask forms into dictionaries

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have a form which looks like that

[image]

Is there any way that I could recieve this data in backend as a not flattend dictionaries?
Like this:

```
{
  device_type: 2,
  input: {
      input_type: 3,
      path: '',
      .
      .
  }
}
```

I tried to do combine multiple forms in wtf

```
class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    resolutions = ["(640, 480)", "(1280, 720)", "(1920, 1080)"]

    input_type = wtforms.StringField("Input type")
    path = wtforms.StringField("Path")
    brightness = wtforms.StringField("Brightness")
    resoultion = wtforms.SelectField("Resolution", choices=resolutions)
    auto_focus = wtforms.BooleanField("Auto focus")


class ConfigForm(FlaskForm):
    input = wtforms.FormField(InputForm)
    device_type = wtforms.StringField("Device type")
```

But it only adds a prefix to form data:

```
{
  device_type: 2,
  input-input_type: 3,
  input-path: "",
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: according to the docs you will need to use [FormFields](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#field-enclosures)

Comment: @gold_cy I did use those, and it just adds prefix to data name, as I showed in my question.

Comment: write a helper python function that will aggregate the data in desired format. what is the problem?

Comment: Well it's better to not write such function if there is other way to do it. And I'm asking if there is such way.